# Why was I banned. Posted question and answer, question accepted answer banned

Tags: discussion

I'm Baffled.  I had a problem with some hardware looked at the forum but didn't find the answer.  After further research I cured the problem and posted a question and answer so others could benefit from my discovery.  When I looked today, the question was there with some comments but no answer.  I tried to repost the answer and discovered I had been banned from answering.  I had to post the answer as a comment.  The question has been put on hold because it lacks detail but the answer provided some of the detail.

I understand that the ban is temporary but it suggests that when lifted, I need to edit my posts.  Looking at my account, that amounts to one question.  Should I have provided the answer as part of the question?  When I first posted the answer, I was warned that I had offended before and I might be banned, but I am sure my answer satisfied the guidelines.  Also, how can I find out what I did to offend previously.

Comment: I presume you are referring to this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/682255/boot-problems-on-new-install-gigabyte-ga-j1800n-d2h-using-intel-j1800-soc

Comment: If you are using mint you should really go to  -  http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

You have 4 deleted answers that factor into the answer ban (and none on the post fossfreedom mentioned above, so it doesn't look like your original answer was ever actually posted).

Unfortunately 2 of them aren't even attempts to answer the question, more comments. The other 2 do attempt to answer the question (they're actually exact duplicates), but both mention Mint and refer to a package that doesn't exist in the latest version of Ubuntu. It does exist in several older, still supported versions however, so I will undelete one of those answers with a slight edit to make it more apparent that the answers are still relevant (I'll also be closing the other question as a duplicate of the first, since they are asking the same thing and the answers are the same).

Sorry for the confusion on those answers. It helps if you are going to mention Mint to make it very obvious the answer still applies to Ubuntu, otherwise this is likely to happen again.  It looks like this (and an upvote on that one answer) has unbanned you. Please be very careful what you post as answers otherwise this is likely to happen again.

As to your question, I'm not sure we can really help you here. We don't support "tailored" versions of ubuntu since anything or everything could be changed or different and that has led to many problems in the past. You would probably be much better off over on https://unix.stackexchange.com/. If you want drop by [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) and post a link to your U&L question, sometimes people are willing to go out of their way to help anyway, even if it isn't official Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I asked the wrong question.

Comment: That should have been 

I'm sorry, I think I asked the wrong question.   It should have been "HOW DO I FIND OUT WHAT I HAVE GOT WRONG".   You have listed 4 offences, but when I originally looked at my account there was nothing there.  Now I can see the question that you restored (thank you) but can't examine (or indeed challenge) the other three incidents.  I remember the post now I see it but I don't think I got any feedback when it was deleted.  I have no idea what the other posts were and can't comment.  Isn't the defendant entitled to see the evidence?

Comment: And whilst I'm here ranting, you need to make it clear above the comment box that [Enter] posts the comment rather than inserting a line break.  Also, not to destroy the comment layout by replacing line breaks with nothing when posters have worked out how to put them in.  It would also help if those who,  having made this mistake, are editing their post to know that there is a 5 minute deadline BEFORE they start to edit rather than when they post it.   I get a lot of interruptions which forum work has to fit round.

Comment: Yes, you can see the other posts. I would normally have linked them in my answer but it was late and I guess I forgot. Here they are: [1](http://askubuntu.com/questions/481693/virtualbox-usb-add-device-filter-does-not-work-under-14-04/558601#558601), [2](http://askubuntu.com/questions/171143/how-to-prevent-my-screen-from-either-dimming-or-the-screen-lock-starting-when-wa/600848#600848), [3](http://askubuntu.com/questions/149448/why-is-disk-utility-palimpsest-the-default-and-not-gparted/674495#674495). You really need to stop thinking of this as us vs you. That's completely not the way it is.

Comment: Hi @Seth.  If you get a chance, have a look at my other question - <http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14510/isnt-it-time-to-review-mint-policy>.  If Bill Gates ever glances in this direction, he'll have plenty to laugh at!